# Make Trello board private, but visible to those with link

Tags: trello, links, permissions

I have a private Trello board that I want to make invisible to the public, but visible to those that have the link to it. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible but I could use this feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is making them members of the board or of the organization that "includes" the board not doable for you? Trello only supports *Public / Organization only / Board members only* settings.